# Adapter Android (Java) как реализован.

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста вообще какие основные функции адаптера и как он реализован в общих чертах(без кучи кода). Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Адаптер - это как бы прослойка между данными и реализацией. Вся работа происходит в getView() методе. Советуют всегда использовать паттерн ViewHolder. Вот код "без наворотов":

```
    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public MyAdapter (Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;

        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: класс `MyAdapter` должен иметь модификатор `static`

Comment: @Garf1eld нет, не обязательно.

Comment: Если static class ViewHolder вынести из класса, то не обязательно :)

Answer (score 1):

В ответе выше не правильно реализирован паттерн ViewHolder. Правильно будет так:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        return convertView;
    }
```